# Wijmo Grid Row Max Height

Tags: node.js, wijmo5, wijmo-grid

I want to add text wrapping function for all cells and header items (cell height up to 3 lines)

1. If it cannot be displayed in one line, the characters are wrapped and displayed.
2. The maximum cell height is 3 rows.
3. If characters are hidden even after displaying 3 lines, display "..." at the end of the sentence to indicate that there is a continuation of the characters.

How can I achieve this in grapecity wijmo grid?

When text is small than 3 lines, then row height adjust according to text, if text is larger than 3 lines row height does not exceed more than 50px (Max height 50px)

How can I achieve this?

```
const grid = new wijmo.grid.FlexGrid(gridId, {
      autoGenerateColumns: false,
      deferResizing: true,
      validateEdits: false,
      allowSorting: wijmo.grid.AllowSorting.MultiColumn,
      // headersVisibility: wijmo.grid.HeadersVisibility.Column,
      copyHeaders: wijmo.grid.HeadersVisibility.Column,
      itemsSource: [],
      columns: typeof column === 'string' ? columnSetting(column) : column,

      itemsSourceChanged: itemsSourceChanged,
      beginningEdit: beginningEdit,
      selectionChanged: debounce(selectionChanged, 50),
      pasting: pasting,
    });

theGrid = grid.initGrid('#grid', url);

theGrid = grid.initGrid('#grid', url);
    theGrid.initialize({
      allowResizing: 'Both',
      formatItem: formatItem,
      beginningEdit: beginningEdit,
      cellEditEnded: cellEditEnded,
      updatedView: checkButtonEnable,
      updatedLayout: grid.attachMaps(dataMaps),
      scrollPositionChanged: (wijmoGrid) => {
        if (grid.isScroll(wijmoGrid, filter, endFlg)) {
          nextFlg = true;
          limitNum = limit.PART;
          getData();
        }
      },
      itemValidator: function (rowIdx, colIdx) { return itemValidator(theGrid, rowIdx, colIdx); }
    });
```